# How to update Xcode using software update if the App Store is not accessible or download?

Tags: install, xcode, software-update

There is a related question, "How to download Xcode 13 if the App Store is not accessible?" But if you already have XCode installed and run the following command:

```
xcode-select --install
```

The following message appears:

```
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" in System Settings to install updates
```

What is the command to update XCode via the command line or by download?

I know the following basic commands:

**List all updates:**

```
softwareupdate -l
```

**To install a specific update** in the list, use the following format, but replacing NAME with the update's identifier:

```
softwareupdate -i NAME

softwareupdate --install 'macOS High Sierra 10.13.3 Supplemental Update-'
```

**To install all available updates** for your system type the command:

```
softwareupdate -i -a
```

But I don't see one for XCode:

```
Software Update Tool

Finding available software
No new software available.
```

Comment: What macOS are you on? What's your current Xcode version?

Comment: @Tetsujin OSX 13.3.1. Xcode 12.4. I have xcode installed mostly for the command line tools.

Comment: Ahh, OK - not sure the fix, but you're two whole Xcode versions behind.

Comment: Download XCode from the Developer portal.